# How do I write sql to bring this back

Tags: t-sql

I need to bring back distinct rows from table A. I need to take employee 300 from table b and c. He can see siteid 1 and 2 and EmployingActivityId 10 and 50 and  What is the most efficient way to gram these records

```
Table A
id   Employeeid   SiteId   EmployingActivityId
1       123          1        10
2       124          2        10
3       125          3       30
4       126         2        40
5    127            5        50
6    128            2        60


Table b
employeeid    SiteID
300                1
300                2
400                2


table C
employeeid    EmployingActivityId
300               10
300               50
400               20
```

I know this is not right, but....

```
select distinct id, Employeeid from tableA as a
inner join
    (select siteID from tableb (where employee = 300) on tableb.siteID = tableA.siteid
inner join
    (select siteID from tablec (where employee = 300) on tablec.EmployingActivityId = tableA.EmployingActivityId
```

I need to bring back from table A

```
id     Employeeid
1    123
2    124
5    127
6    128
```

Comment: can you clarify why you need tables b and c? on what basis or condition are 1,2,5,6 selected?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
declare @a as table(
    id int
    ,employeeId int
    ,siteId int
    ,employeeActivityId int
)

declare @b as table(
    employeeID int
    ,siteId int
)

declare @c as table(
    employeeid int
    ,employeeActivitatyID int
)

insert into @a values (1,123,1,10)
insert into @a values (2,124,2,10)
insert into @a values (3,125,3,30)
insert into @a values (4,126,2,40)
insert into @a values (5,127,5,50)
insert into @a values (6,128,2,60)

insert into @b values (300,1)
insert into @b values (300,2)
insert into @b values (400,2)

insert into @c values (300,10)
insert into @c values (300,50)
insert into @c values (400,20)


select distinct id, a.employeeid
from @a a
left join @b b
    on a.siteId = b.siteId
left join @c c
    on a.employeeActivityId = c.employeeActivitatyID
where 300 in (b.employeeID, c.employeeId)
```